# Creating a simple Makefile to build a shared library

Tags: gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

I am trying to create a very basic hand crafted Makefile to create a shared library to illustrate a point.

This is what I have so far:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC    = gcc
FLAGS        = -std=gnu99 -Iinclude
CFLAGS       = -fPIC -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -march=native -ggdb3
DEBUGFLAGS   = -O0 -D _DEBUG
RELEASEFLAGS = -O2 -D NDEBUG -combine -fwhole-program

TARGET  = example.so
SOURCES = $(shell echo src/*.c)
HEADERS = $(shell echo include/*.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

PREFIX = $(DESTDIR)/usr/local
BINDIR = $(PREFIX)/bin

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

When I run `make`, it attempts to build an application - and `ld` fails because it can't resolve `main()`.

Problem seems to be with `CFLAGS` - I have specified `-fPIC` but that is not working - what am I doing wrong?

#### Edit

I added the `-shared` flag as suggested, when I run `make`, I got this error:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Iinclude -fPIC -shared -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -march=native -ggdb3 -O0 -D _DEBUG -o example.so src/example.o
/usr/bin/ld: src/example.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
src/example.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [example.so] Error 1
```

Which seems to be suggesting to revert back to `-fPIC` only.

BTW, my new `CFLAGS` setting is:

```
CFLAGS       = -fPIC -shared -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -march=native -ggdb3
```

I am running gcc v4.4.3 on Ubuntu 10.0.4.

Comment: I think you're missing `-shared` in the `CFLAGS`, and `ld` attempts to create an executable this way.

Comment: I'd use `$(wildcard src/*.c)` instead of `$(shell echo src/*.c)`, but I'm wondering if there are any serious differences.

Comment: A more appropriate title for this question would be "Creating a shared library - what's wrong with these compile and link options?" You're presenting this as a problem with your makefile, but there's nothing wrong with it. It delivers exactly what you're asking of it.

Comment: Kindly check link also http://stackoverflow.com/a/43347369/1485176

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution was to modify the XXFLAGS as follows:

```
FLAGS        = # -std=gnu99 -Iinclude
CFLAGS       = -fPIC -g #-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3
LDFLAGS      = -shared
```

Answer (score 18):

Compile with `-shared`:

```
gcc -o libfoo.so module1.o module2.o -shared
```

(This also works on MingW under Windows to produce DLLs.)

Comment: Well, if you know how to write a makefile, then you know where to put your compiler options... `-shared` is a linker option, so I'd add it to `LDFLAGS`. *Edit* Whoops, you don't *have* `LDFLAGS`. I recommend creating that variable and adding it to the link command.

Comment: Given that this is a question on stackoverflow, not everyone coming here will  know how to write a makefile, or know where to put compiler options, so clarifying the basics like this absolutely makes sense.

Answer (score 11):

Example for C++ files. I've also included a `clean` target.

```
.PHONY : clean

CPPFLAGS= -fPIC -g
LDFLAGS= -shared

SOURCES = $(shell echo *.cpp)
HEADERS = $(shell echo *.h)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

FIKSENGINE_LIBDIR=../../../../lib
FIKSENGINE_INCDIR=../../../../include

TARGET=$(FIKSENGINE_LIBDIR)/tinyxml.so

all: $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you try to build `so` file, you probably need `-shared`.

Answer (score 1):

this is my goto makefile rule for so files:

```
%.so: %.o ; $(LINK.c) $(LDFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@
```

can be used like so

```
CFLAGS+=-fPIC

libmyfoo.so:  # create from libmyfoo.o

# or 

libmyfoo.so: myfoo.o  # create from myfoo.o
```