# Building shared libraries in subdirectories

Tags: c, r, makefile

I am trying to build an R package that uses some C code. I have a C library that is compiled into an executable, that can be called from the command line. There is a Makefile associated with it.

I am trying to grok the information [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars), where it says

> If you want to create and then link to a library, say using code in a
>   subdirectory, use something like

```
 .PHONY: all mylibs

 all: $(SHLIB)
 $(SHLIB): mylibs

 mylibs:
         (cd subdir; make)
```

> Be careful to create all the necessary dependencies, as there is a no
>   guarantee that the dependencies of all
>   will be run in a particular order (and some of the CRAN build machines
>   use multiple CPUs and parallel makes).

If I create a new subdirectory of the `src` folder in my package, called `someLibrary`, with the code and Makefile unchanged, and in turn, in the original `Makevars` file for my package I add the above code unchanged, then I will be able to build that shared library to be exported using `useDynLib`?

---

### Edit 1:

Following information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096015/creating-a-simple-make-file-to-create-a-shared-library-whats-wrong-with-this-m), I changed the `Makefile` to create a shared library by adding

```
CFLAG = -fPIC -g -O3 
LDFLAGS= -shared
```

However, this leads to the problem that the `.so` file is not exported directly to the `libs` directory of the package. If I hard code the path into the target, then the file is sent to the `libs` directory of the package (this is all by the way of calls to `R CMD INSTALL myPackage`).

---

### Edit 2:

Lastly, I would like to know how to make calls to the shared library, given that it has a `main()` method that I could call from the command line executable.

What is the procedure to expose this to the R `NAMESPACE`, so that it can be called via `.Call`?

PS.  Please let me know if I should make the last bit a separate question.

Comment: Maybe you should compile them to `.o`, and put these `.o` in `OBJECTS` of `Makevars`.

R will link them and load them correctly if the wrapper is correct.

Comment: Have you investigated the possibility of using `automake` and `libtool`?  I know that GNU Autotools is quite a heavyweight solution, but it does make compiling a shared object in one directory and then linking against it from another quite achievable.

Comment: @PeterBrett Peter, thanks for your comment. I still struggle from time to time with this. Would you be able to post a simple example of the entire tool chain to help me get started and adapt for my purpose? If you want I can add a bounty to this question. :)

Comment: @fg-nu I will post a minimal hello-world-in-shared-library example this evening - might take a while to put together. Bounties are always appreciated! :-)

Comment: @PeterBrett Bountied!

Answer (score 18):

The original question author asked, in the comments on the question, for an example of using **Automake**, **Libtool** and `LDADD` to link a program compiled in one directory with a shared library compiled in a second directory. **This is a complete, standalone, fully worked example of how to compile a library and program in separate directories of the same source tree using GNU Autotools.**

### Directory structure

We need to set up a directory structure as follows:

```
├ A/
│ ├ Makefile.am
│ ├ helloworld.c
│ └ helloworld.h
├ B/
│ ├ Makefile.am
│ └ foo.c
├ configure.ac
└ Makefile.am
```

The shared library will be compiled in directory `A/`, and the program that uses it in directory `B/`.

### Writing the source code

There are three source files.

`A/helloworld.c` is the source code of the library. It exports one procedure, `say_hello()`, which prints the message "Hello world!" to standard output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "helloworld.h"

void
say_hello (void)
{
  printf ("Hello world!\n");
}
```

`A/helloworld.h` is the header file that contains the declaration of the `say_hello()` function.  It only has one line:

```
void say_hello (void);
```

Finally, `B/foo.c` is the source code of the program that uses the shared library.  It includes the library's header file, and calls `say_hello()`.

```
#include <helloworld.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  say_hello ();
  return 0;
}
```

### Compiling the library

We will use Automake and Libtool to compile the shared library.  Both of these tools are  very powerful, and actually remarkably well-documented.  The manuals ([Automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html), [Libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/index.html)) are definitely worth reading.

The `A/Makefile.am` file is used by `automake` to control the compilation of the library.

```
# We're going to compile one libtool library, installed to ${libdir},
# and named libhelloworld.
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libhelloworld.la

# List the source files used by libhelloworld.
libhelloworld_la_SOURCES = helloworld.c

# We install a single header file to ${includedir}
include_HEADERS = helloworld.h
```

### Compiling the program

The `B/Makefile.am` file controls compilation of the library.  We need to use the [`LDADD`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#index-LDADD) variable to tell `automake` to link against the library we compiled earlier.

```
# Compile one program, called foo, and installed to ${bindir}, with a single C
# source file.
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.c

# Link against our uninstalled copy of libhelloworld.
LDADD = $(top_builddir)/A/libhelloworld.la

# Make sure we can find the uninstalled header file.
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/A
```

### Controlling the build

Finally, we need a top level `Makefile.am` to tell Automake how to build the project, and a `configure.ac` file to tell Autoconf how to find the required tools.

The top-level `Makefile.am` is fairly straightforward:

```
# Compile two subdirectories.  We need to compile A/ first so the shared library is
# available to link against.
SUBDIRS = A B

# libtool requires some M4 scripts to be added to the source tree.  Make sure that
# Autoconf knows where to find them.
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

Finally, the `configure.ac` file tells Autoconf how to create the `configure` script.

```
AC_INIT([libhelloworld], 1, peter@peter-b.co.uk)

# This is used to help configure check whether the source code is actually present, and
# that it isn't being run from some random directory.
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([A/helloworld.c])

# Put M4 macros in the m4/ subdirectory.
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

# We're using automake, but we want to turn off complaints about missing README files
# etc., so we need the "foreign" option.
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])

# We need a C compiler
AC_PROG_CC

# Find the tools etc. needed by libtool
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL

# configure needs to generate three Makefiles.
AC_CONFIG_FILES([A/Makefile
                 B/Makefile
                 Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

### Testing it out

Run:

```
$ autoreconf -i
$ ./configure
$ make
$ B/foo
```

You should see the required output: "Hello world!"

Comment: Peter, do you know any R? Can you figure out if this will work with the R packaging & compiling infrastructure?

Comment: Hi @fg_nu, I've just read some of the relevant R documentation and I suspect not (also, OMG that compiling & packaging stuff is pretty gnarly). I'll try and figure it out later!

Comment: Peter, no worries. :) Thanks for your great answer. I will go through it and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Peter, I am going to give you the bounty, but not the check mark, since I hope to spend some time to build on your answer and make it about R as the original question was about R. I hope that is okay, let me know if not. :)

Comment: You're very kind! I'm sorry I couldn't answer your question exactly!  I keep meaning to come back and look into the problem -- I know other people who use R who've asked similar things -- but lack of time...

Comment: Shouldn't `LDADD = $(top_builddir)/A/libhelloworld.la` be `foo_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/A/libhelloworld.la`?

Comment: am I missing something when I get `ld: cannot link -lhelloworld` *edit*, yup, i wrote -lhelloworld literally in the LDFLAGS, my bad

Answer (score 2):

callable.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

To get a .so file from the C file callable.c use

```
R CMD SHLIB callable.c
```

So now we have callable.so

R normally requires that all C arguments be pointers, but if your main method ignores argc, then we can get around this. So to call main from callable.so from R we can write a method like so.

```
main <- function() {
    dyn.load("callable.so")
    out <- .C("main", argc=0, argv="")
}
```

Calling that main function will run the C main function.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually fairly insightful. I will try to put this together with Peter's answer to get the whole thing going.