# How can I compile with shared library if I use Autotools

Tags: c, makefile, autotools, automake, libtool

I have two C programs named `drive.c` and `mylib.c`.

`drive.c` is main module `mylib.c` is sub modulle that I want work as shared library .

I can compile them with following step and run.

```
gcc –fPIC –g –c –Wall mylib.c 

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmylib.so.1 -o /c/opt/lib/libmylib.so.1.0.1 mylib.o -lc

gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  -I./ -L/c/opt/lib -o drive.exe drive.c –l:libmylib.so.1
```

Now I want know is How can I compile them by `autotools` as same effect of above way ?

What and how do I have to edit `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` for compile them?

Comment: Learning how to use autotools needs some efforts, you could use [Autotools: A Practioner's Guide to GNU Autoconf, Automake, and Libtool](http://www.amazon.com/Autotools-Practioners-Autoconf-Automake-Libtool/dp/1593272065) as a starting point.

Comment: look here http://www.openismus.com/documents/linux/building_libraries/building_libraries

Comment: I recently provided a fully worked example on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22182051/266449

Comment: I can build @Petr Brett's way.