# makefile for creating (.so) file from existing files

Tags: c, linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I have 4 files: **1.c**, **1.h**, **2.c**, **2.h**.
I need a makefile, which will create a dynamic library (.so) from those 4 files.
I have tried to write a makefile like this:

library.so : 1.c 1.h 2.c 2.h

but it did not work. It would be great, if someone helps me, thanks.

Comment: They are header files - not part of a .so file

Comment: then how should my makefile look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like

```
 CC=gcc
 CFLAGS= -Wall -g -O -fPIC
 RM= rm -f
 .PHONY: all clean

 all: library.so
 clean:
      $(RM) *.o *.so

 library.so: 1.o 2.o
      $(LINK.c) -shared $^ -o $@

 1.o: 1.c 1.h 2.h

 2.o: 2.c 1.h 2.h
```

But this is untested! I am assuming Linux with [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), and a directory containing only the source code of your library (with the above `Makefile`), which might be bad practice -you might want a test case- (you could have a special `Makefile` rule for `%.pic.o` depending on `%.c`, etc...)

Hints: use `make -p` to understand the builtin rules. Then `make --trace` or (with [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/)) `remake -x` to understand a bit more what `make`  is doing.

Read also [Drepper's paper: How to Write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26672678/841108), ...

Comment: typo here, $^ instead of $<.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is:

```
CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
CXXFLAGS += -O3
x.so: 1.o 2.o
    $(LINK.cc) -shared $^ $(LOADLIBS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Slightly more advanced:

```
CC    = gcc
FLAGS        = # -std=gnu99 -Iinclude
CFLAGS       = -fPIC -g #-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3
LDFLAGS      = -shared

DEBUGFLAGS   = -O0 -D _DEBUG
RELEASEFLAGS = -O2 -D NDEBUG -combine -fwhole-program

TARGET  = example.so
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)


all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Don't use `$(shell echo ./*.c)` but just `$(wildcard *.c)`

Comment: okay, thank you so much, I wish I could rise your reputation, but I  
unfortunatelly I cant because I am too new :(

Comment: you forgot to use LDFLAGS  in last line, so it results to error, when gcc complaining about no main() function, but in shared lib there could be no main() function...

Answer (score 3):

```
CC = gcc                                # C compiler
CFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -g         # C flags
LDFLAGS = -shared                       # linking flags
RM = rm -f                              # rm command
TARGET_LIB = sh_main.so                 # target lib

SRCS = add.c sub.c main.c               # source file
DEPS = header.h                         # header file
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)                    # object file

.PHONY: all
all: ${TARGET_LIB}

$(TARGET_LIB): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ $^       # -o $@ says, put the output of the compilation in the file named on the left side of the :

$(SRCS:.c=.d):%.d:%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $< >$@      # the $< is the first item in the dependencies list, and the CFLAGS macro is defined as above
include $(SRCS:.c=.d)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        -${RM} ${TARGET_LIB} ${OBJS} $(SRCS:.c=.d)
```

After the shared library created successfully. We need to install it.

Become the root user. 

Copy the shared library into standard directory "**/usr/lib**". 

Run **ldcofig** command.

Recompile your .c file with shared library.
root@Admin:~/C/SharedLibrary# gcc -c main.c
root@Admin:~/C/SharedLibrary# gcc -o main main.o sh_main.so

root@Admin:~/C/SharedLibrary# **ldd** main

**Note:** In my case.

**main.c:** main C file

**sh_main.so:** shared library.

Comment: Why the recompile? Is it just because /usr/lib is normally chown'd by root? Or is it because...In any case, this served as successful template for the same problem. Haven't done the recompile yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no gnu make expert, this seems reasonable to me

```
CFLAGS+=-fPIC
%.so: ; $(LINK.c) $(LDFLAGS) -shared $^ -o $@

library.so: 1.o 2.o  # default target first

# changes to `1.h` imply `1.o` needs to be rebuilt
1.o: 1.h  
2.o: 2.h
```