# How to compile with a .o file that was compiled with other .o files (C99)

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, c99

consider `c.c` a code that includes `a.h` and `b.h`, and `main.c` a code that includes `c.h`
i tried to compile it like so

```
gcc --std=c99 -o a.o -c a.c
gcc --std=c99 -o b.o -c b.c
gcc --std=c99 -o c.o -c c.c a.o b.o
```

but when I run the last one, gcc yells at me

```
gcc --std=c99 -o c.o -c c.c a.o b.o
gcc: warning: a.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: b.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

and then when I try to compile the main.c file using `gcc -o main main.c c.o` it says that there are a lot of undefined references, which is predictable once the `c` file was not correctly compiled.

I've seen some similar questions here at stackoverflow, but I couldn't get it to work neither way.

I'm on Arch Linux running gcc v4.9.2-3

Comment: Have you tried just `gcc --std=c99 -o  c.o b.o a.o c.c`?

Comment: On which operating system, with which version of GCC? Why do you ask? Don't you simply want to link some executable? Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: @ForceBru if I do, it tells me `undefined reference to main`, because c.o is not the final program, it will later be used together with main.c to create the final executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is `-std=c99` with a single dash.

I guess you are on Linux.

Then, you always should pass `-Wall -Wextra -g` (especially since you are a newbie) to `gcc` : `-Wall` ask for *nearly* all warnings, `-Wextra` for even more warnings, `-g` ask for debug information.

At last, you want to produce an executable `myprog` (don't name executables as `c.o`, this is supposed to be an object file) with

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -o myprog c.c a.o b.o
```

You need to remove any `-c` since you want the linking to happen.

If you really mean -but that is very unusual today, better make shared libraries!- to agglomerate several object files into one `all.o` (to be linked later with other objects) you might try the [`-r` linker option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -r c.c a.o b.o -o all.o
```

<sup>But last time I tried it was in the previous century, so details could be wrong.</sup>

There are very few reasons to agglomerate objects using the `-r` linker option. Unless you really know what you are doing, you are very probably wrong (in trying `-r`).

Perhaps you want to make a [software library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29). These days it is much better to make a shared library. A shared library (technically an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object)  should contain [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). So, assuming you have three translation units `t1.c`, `t2.c`, `t3.c` you first compile them as PIC :

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -fPIC t1.c -c -o t1.pic.o
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -fPIC t2.c -c -o t2.pic.o
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -fPIC t3.c -c -o t3.pic.o
```

then you link all these PIC object files into a shared library `libmyt.so`

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -shared \
    t1.pic.o t2.pic.o t3.pic.o \
    -o libmyt.so
```

Later you'll use this shared library e.g. as

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g main.o -o myprog -Wl,-rpath . libmyt.so
```

or as

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g main.o -o myprog -Wl,-rpath . -L. -lmyt
```

<sup>You might consider static linking with `ar` to make a static library `libmyt.a` but I don't recommend that.</sup>

---

Of course, you'll debug your program using `gdb ./myprog` and you could try running it with `./myprog`. To use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), try `valgrind ./myprog`

If you have several translation units, better learn how to use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Read the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26689798/841108) and [these hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108).

Comment: What I really meant was to agglomerate the objects to use later, like you said, but now ld (the linker) is telling me that `ld: cannot find -lgcc_s` I couldn't find any references to -r on gcc man page, what is it really supposed to mean?

Comment: `-r` is a linker option. But if you want to agglomerate objects, make a static library (use `ar`) or better yet a shared object.